# Appcelerator Studio build fails due to inclusion of native module analytics.google

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, appcelerator-titanium

When we try to run app on iOS Simulator, build always fails with below errors-

```
[WARN] :   The app is using native modules (ti.safaridialog,analytics.google) that do not support arm64 simulators, we will exclude arm64. This may fail if you're on an arm64 Apple Silicon device.
[ERROR] :  2021-06-04 11:00:55.176 xcodebuild[10841:1328412] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID F56A1938-XXXXXXXX-493D-87EE6C415E4D for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/RSImageOptimPlugin.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld /Users/amar/Documents/MyApp-Appcel-build/MyApp-New-Setup/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/Project normal x86_64
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

tiapp.xml-

```
<modules>
      <module platform="iphone">ti.safaridialog</module>
      <module platform="iphone">analytics.google</module>
</modules>
```

When we remove analytics.google module, it builds well.

Please suggest.

```
Operating System
  Name                        = macOS
  Version                     = 11.3
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 12.13.0
  npm Version                 = 6.12.0
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.3.2
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 9.0.3.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/amar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.0.3.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone
```

Note- earlier we were able to build same source code , not sure what updates causing this issue now.

Comment: Build  also fails when run app on iphone device , below error logs -                                             
                                                                                                                                           
[INFO]  Invoking xcodebuild
[ERROR] 2021-06-04 18:42:48.701 xcodebuild[9816:1890487]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
[ERROR] Details:  (null) deviceType from 0fbc9912d1ea30674a5bdb31f3c9e5c was NULL when -platform called.

Comment: Tried using module ti.ga module , but its also causing build to be failed-                                 <module platform="iphone" version="2.4.2">ti.ga</module>